# Validation messages do not show up anymore

Tags: validation, jsf

I need to validate if a `<p:spinner>` value is between a set range.

```
<p:spinner id="minutes" min="0" max="1000" value="#{printerSettings.t}"  size ="1">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="1000" />
    <p:ajax update="NewTime"/>
</p:spinner>
<h:message for="minutes" style="color:red" />
```

and

```
<p>Number of copies (Max of 50) :
    <p:spinner id ="Copies" min="1" max="50" value="#{printerSettings.p}" size ="1"> <!-- allows the user a choice of up to 50, this is more than enough for any situation, if needed this can be removed or raised -->
        <p:ajax update="p"/>
        <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="50" />
    </p:spinner>
    <div class="whiteSpace"/>   
    <h:outputText value="Copies that will be printed: &nbsp; #{printerSettings.p}" id="p"/>

    <h:message for="Copies" style="color:red" />
</p>
```

This was working before, but now no validation happens, no error etc. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

EDIT

```
 <div id="site_content">
        <div id="content">
            <h:body>


                <h:form onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
                    <p>

                    In how many minutes time would you like to have your job sent to the printer ?  
                    <div class="whiteSpace"/>
                    <p:spinner id="minutes" min="0" max="1000" value="#{printerSettings.t}"  size ="1">
                        <p:ajax update="NewTime"/>
                        <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="1000" />
                    </p:spinner>

                    <h:message for="minutes" style="color:red" />

                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>

                    The time the print job will be sent to the printer will be : 
                    <!--<p:button actionListener="{otherBean.setTValue(printerSettings.t)}" value="Set Val" /> Currently causing an error -->
                    <br></br>
                    <h:outputText value="#{printerSettings.getNewTime()}" id="NewTime"/>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <p:commandButton  type="submit" action="#{email.mail(printerSettings.t, printerSettings.p, printerSettings.paperSize, printerSettings.duplex, printerSettings.orienation, printerSettings.printer)}" onclick="Thankyou()" value="Print" />

<p:button outcome="index" value="Homepage" icon="ui-icon-home">  
                    </p:button>  

                </h:form>
            </h:body>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                    function Thankyou()
                    {
                        alert("Sent to the printing holding queue, you may close this app now or carry on using this app, your work will still print out ");
                        //location.href = 'index.xhtml';

                    }
```

is that ok ? i can post more code if required, as said in my comment the validation seems to be working, it is just the errors messages that are now displaying at all

EDIT

```
                <p:commandButton  type="submit" update ="minutes2 Copies2"  action="#{email.mail(printerSettings.t, printerSettings.p, printerSettings.paperSize, printerSettings.duplex, printerSettings.orienation, printerSettings.printer)}" onclick="Thankyou()" value="Print" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate an value submitted by a spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120189/how-to-validate-an-value-submitted-by-a-spinner). If the answer provided there didn't answered what you were looking for, then you shouldn't have accepted in the first place.

Comment: Did you expect the message to show up when you change the input, or when you submit the form? Currently, they will indeed not show up when you change the input, but I'm not sure if that is intented as the code is not in a fullworthy SSCCE flavor (you should provide exactly sufficiently code so that someone else (and yourself!) can reproduce exactly your problem when copypasted into a completely blank playground project with everything set to defaults).

Comment: Thanks, i am hoping the message will display after the user presses submit, i have found out by testing the code, it is indeed validating the inputs, will not submit if the values are over the validated range, but no error message ! will post the code up in a sec

Comment: Code added, it seems the only issue is the messages not showing up after the submit button is pressed

Answer (score 4):

You're validating and submitting the form by ajax, but you're nowhere instructing JSF to update the message components on ajax response. They do not update by themselves.

You need to give the message components an ID and refer them in ajax update.

E.g.

```
<h:message id="foo" ... />
```

and

```
<p:ajax ... update="foo" />
```

and

```
<p:commandButton ... update="foo" />
```

You can if necessary specify multiple IDs spaceseparated.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="foo bar" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that has the messages showing up :), one final question, on submit i have some javascript that displays a simple message, but this always displays, is there anyway to display this message only if all validation has completed ok

Comment: Make use of `#{facesContext.validationFailed}` in EL context or `args.validationFailed` in JS context of PrimeFaces `oncomplete`. For detailed answers or new questions, please press `Ask Question` button instead of abusing comments of other questions for that.